# Finding the area between two curves?

Tags: calculus

I was trying to "discover" a way of finding the length of a curve, and I can across something:

Let's say I want to find the length of $y=x^2+1$ between $0$ and $1$, and let's say the length is $L$.

So let's look at $y=x^2+1$ and $y=x^2+1-c$, where $c$ is a positive constant less than $1$. The area between the graphs is $$\int ^{1}_{0} x^2+1-\int ^{1}_{0} x^2+1-c=c$$
I thought that that same area might also be able to be represented as $c \cdot L$ as $c$ approaches $0$, but this idea is obviously wrong because if we make the are between the curves (which is $c$) equal to the other "formula", we would get $c=Lc$, so from this $L$ would have to be one, but this is wrong. However, I have seen how one time the area between two concentric circles (which were ery close together) is approximated by the circumference of the small circle multiplied by the distance between the circles. Why does this method not work here?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking informally...

The region between your two curves is made up of infinitely many vertical line segments, each $c$ units tall.  If you lined them up by shifting each one vertically, you'd have a rectangle of height $c$ and width $1$ (since it extends from $x=0$ to $x=1$).  That's where your $L=1$ comes from.

In order to get the right result, the line segments should each be perpendicular to the curve.  That way, at the infinitesimal scale, a short region of the curve, together with its attached line segments, looks like a rectangle with one dimension being the length of the line segments $c$ and the other being a bit of length along the curve ($dL$), and when you add all that up you get roughly $\int c\,dL = cL$, as desired.  In your situation, at infinitesimal scale you've got parallelograms of various shapes, not rectangles, so it comes out all weird.

It works with the circles because the distance between the circles is measured perpendicular to the curves.

See also [Minkowski content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_content).